# an exercise about changing the measure and convergence in $L^1$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

this is exercise 17.12 from probability essentials written by jacod & protter.

Suppose $lim_{n→∞} X_n = X$ a.s. Let $Y = sup_n |X_n − X|$. Show $Y < ∞$
a.s. , and define a new probability measure $Q$ by
$Q(A) = \frac{1}{c}
E (1_A \frac{1}{1 +Y})$  , where   $c = E (\frac{1}{1 +Y})$  .
Show that $X_
n$ tends to $X$ in $L_1$ under the probability measure $Q$.

i've proved that $Y < ∞$
a.s.

cam anyone help me with the second part?

thanks.

Comment: Sorry, brainfart. Proof in two steps: first, note that $E_Q(|X_n-X|)=E_P(Z_n)$ with $Z_n=c^{-1}|X_n-X|/(1+Y)$; second, apply dominated convergence to $(Z_n)$ since $Z_n\to0$ almost surely with $Z_n\leqslant c^{-1}$ almost surely.

Comment: @Did why $Z_n \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: ?? Because $X_n\to X$ almost surely.

Comment: @Did oh! right! but how to prove first claim?

Comment: Which "first claim"?

Comment: @Did first, note that...

Comment: You have been told why...

Answer (score 1):

A strategy could be the following.

1. Show that for any positive random variable $Z$, we have 
   $$\mathbb E_{ Q}(Z)=\frac 1c\mathbb E\left(\frac{Z}{1+Y}   \right).$$
2. Apply this to $Z=|X_n-X|$.

Comment: @ Davide Giraudo for proving first step:$E_Q(Z)=\int Z Q(dx) $,$Q(dx)=\int_{dx}(c(Y+1))^{-1}$ so the statement is proved.right?(i think i must write better)

Comment: After the last equal, $Z$ does not appear anymore, hence it is not correct. First prove it for linear combination of characteristic functions, then approximate.

Comment: for characteristic function of set $A$ we have:$E_Q(1_A)=∫1_AQ(dP)=∫_A Q(dP)=Q(A)=\frac{1}{c}E(1_A\frac{1}{1+Y})$ is my style of writing correct & precise?